# conversion issue while converting

Tags: c#

i want to convert a character into an integer number for processing but it is not picking it

code

```
test = Convert.ToInt32(ch);
Console.WriteLine(test);
if (test >= 0 && test <= 9)
{
    numst[num_count] = test;
    Console.WriteLine(numst[num_count]);
    num_count++;
}
```

test,num_count are integer,numst is a integer array and ch is a character

i want to check that if ch is a number then put it into the integer array

please help me about where i was wrong in logic
thank you

Comment: You forgot to describe what's wrong with your code. Please *add problem description* - error details or expected results

Comment: "it is not picking it" doesn't tell us anything about the problem.  When you step through this in a debugger, how specifically does it fail?  What are the evaluated runtime values?  What *actually happens*?

Comment: sir there is no error in it

Comment: there are two writeline statements in the above code

Comment: @ammadyouasf maybe you should close the question if there is no error?

Comment: the first one is printing the integer values if there is a integer value in 'ch' variable but if there is a integer value ,if statement is not validating it and no value will be saved in the numst array

Comment: sir there is a logical error that is that test can pick the integer value but if i try to put it into numst array it is not putting it because it is not entering into if statement body

Comment: Tell us the value of `ch`, then we can try to reproduce it.

Comment: sir i put 55*12 in the a string and then i put the string into a char array after that throught index by index i try to identify that if there is a number then it will put it into a numst array otherwise there is a stack that is handle the other characters in the input string

Answer (score 2):

If `ch` is a *numeric character* then this doesn't do what you think it does:

```
Convert.ToInt32(ch);
```

For example, the integer value of the character `'9'` is `57`.  According to your `if` condition, the only characters you're expecting are essentially [unprintable characters](http://www.asciitable.com/) (`NUL` through `TAB`).

It sounds like you're looking for `Char.GetNumericValue()`:

```
test = Char.GetNumericValue(ch);
```

Comment: testing your provided code which is to replace Convert.ToInt32(ch) with Char.GetNumericValue(ch);

Comment: sir ch is a char i want to identify that it is a char at that time or it some thing like a '*' or '+' at that moment

Comment: well sir i got my answer

Comment: that is i have to use ASCII character to identify what is in ch variable

Comment: thank you very much for you time for me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if a *digit*, use [`char.IsDigit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh(v=vs.110).aspx). To convert that character to an integer use [`char.GetNumericValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (char.IsDigit(ch))
{
    numst[num_count] = char.GetNumericValue(ch);
    Console.WriteLine(numst[num_count]);
    num_count++;
}
```

`char.IsDigit()` will return `true` for characters between `'0'` and `'9'`, but `false` for e.g. `'*'`.

`char.GetNumericValue()` gives you the numeric value that was *represented* by the character. So a `'9'` is converted to `9`.

`Convert.ToInt32()` instead converts the `char`'s *value* to an `int`. The value of a character like `'9'` is `0x39` or `57`.

Comment: did it can test my input string that is "55*12"

Comment: well i am try your code if i got any issue i let you about it

Comment: @ammadyouasf your english is hard to understand. the code I show tests a single character, not a whole string. You said you are iterating through the string's characters.

Comment: i am trying to enter a string with multiple numbers and multiple operators in it, i have a number array which is numst and a stack where i hold the operators that are basic math operators, i am taking a string from user and the identify that if a character comes then i have to put it into stack and if a number comes then put it into numst, after putting it there i have to perform some operation on my array and stacks

Comment: @ammadyouasf ok, so does it work now?

Comment: sir your code works thank you very much

Comment: i also rate your answer so that your provided solution is in working form

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 methods
1st method

```
if (char.IsDigit(ch))
{
    numst[num_count] = char.GetNumericValue(ch);
    Console.WriteLine(numst[num_count]);
    num_count++;
}
```

2nd method

```
if (ch >= 48 &&  ch<=57)
{
    numst[num_count] = char.GetNumericValue(ch);
    Console.WriteLine(numst[num_count]);
    num_count++;
}
```

both of them are working fine and have some results
thank you for every one help me

Comment: @René Vogt sir how can i rate vote for you